# How to read peer's port number in webmachine resource?

Tags: erlang, port, peer, webmachine

Inside a **Webmachine resource**  Peer's  IP address shall be obtained  using

`PeerIP = wrq:peer(ReqData).`

function  in `ReqData API.`

Is  there any   method to get  **peer's  port**  number  in a Webmachine 
resource ?

Comment: Do you have access to the accepted Socket ?

Comment: No, wrq:sock(ReqData) returns only sockname, infact its the IP address of the server, not the actual socket